# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null console log error

Tags: javascript, console.log

I don't get why i'm having this error in the console log. This code is in the utm source script area. When I click the the error, it redirects me in this area of code.

```
if(utm_source.toLowerCase() == "other"){
  tmpVars = updateQueryStringParameter(tmpVars, "utm_source", "referrer");

  if( tmpVars.charAt( 0 ) === "?" ){
    tmpVars = tmpVars.substr(1);
  }

  trackingVars = tmpVars;
}
```

I've tried to make a static page. The live page doesn't have error but when I downloaded it using wget and transfer it to my xampp, i got this error.

Comment: The error message tells you that `utm_source` is null.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, when it runs, `utm_source` is `null`

Comment: Where and how are you setting `utm_source`? The problem likely originates from there.

Comment: Maybe this script starts to work before the page is loaded completely.